# Adding UnhandledException support to a ViewModel

Tags: wpf

OK - so I have a legacy MC++ app that calls WPF views like they are dialogs.  I have an abstract ViewModel parent class.  Is there a way that I can add UnhandledException handling to my ViewModel so that any exceptions thrown within the ViewModel or it's child implementations can be handled there before propagating out to the MC++ app?

I don't really have an architectural framework to work with.  All the ViewModels and Views implemented to this point have been one-offs :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add exception handling to the method that opens and shows the View as a dialog (ie: wrap the [`Window.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) call).  This should catch any exceptions thrown from within your View or ViewModel, as they're all "launched" from that point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a `Dispatcher`, you can tie into the `Dispatcher.UnhandledException` event, otherwise you can tie into the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += HandleDispatcherException;
someDispatcher.UnhandledException += HandleDispatcherException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleAppDomainException;
```